# Why does number of backslashes increase in strace as opposed to being reduced by bash rules?

Tags: bash, strace

This question is related to [How do I print backslash followed by newline with printf?](https://askubuntu.com/q/999077/295286), where OP tries to print `\\\n` as single backslash followed by newline (not literal `\n`).

While by shell rules it makes sense that `\\` would be expanded as `\` and `\n` as `n` (i.e., shell performs backslash escape to preserve the literal form of the following character), when I perform `strace` it appears as if shell performs something entirely different and I'm struggling to interpret what I'm seeing.

```
$ strace -e execve printf "\\\n"
execve("/usr/bin/printf", ["printf", "\\\\n"], [/* 42 vars */]) = 0
\n+++ exited with 0 +++
```

In other words, what I am seeing is that instead of reduced number of characters that goes into `argv` portion of `execve` syscall, the number actually increases and there's appended an extra backslash.

Passing single quoted  `'\\\\n'` is even more confusing:

```
$ strace -e execve printf '\\\\n'
execve("/usr/bin/printf", ["printf", "\\\\\\\\n"], [/* 42 vars */]) = 0
\\n+++ exited with 0 +++
```

In other words, I'd expect that here shell would pass everything unaltered to `printf` just as in `execve()` from previous command and get same output as `printf "\\\n"`, but it's different.

To some extent I seem to circle around understanding that **pure** `printf`  itself ( the one executed by system) would interpret the argument `\\\n` placed in `argv` portion of `execve()` as backslash and newline. Meanwhile, shell would need to convert `\\\n` typed in by user to match its own rules, but I am struggling to verbalize what exactly is happening with multiple backslashes.

Answer (score 4):

`strace` displays the string in C string syntax, where a single backslash is shown as `\\`, a newline as `\n`, and so on.

What is passed to `execve` is what the `puts` function would print when given the string literal that `strace` prints as arguments in the C source code.

Comment: This is by far the more intelligible answer here. Terse and up to the point. I took the liberty to add a paragraph. +1

Answer (score 1):

The shell is doing very little to your strings that are delimited with double quotes, since the only escaping that applies is the unescaping of `\\` to `\` before passing the argument to the invoked program (one of the few escaping rules that applies in double-quoted strings), and nothing at all to your strings that are delimited with single-quotes.

`strace`, on the other hand, is trying to write out something that looks roughly like C source code, albeit that this is not precisely what C language function calls look like, re-escaping any `\`s.

So:

- In

  ```
  % strace -e execve printf '!\n'
  execve("/usr/bin/printf", ["printf", "!\\n"], [/* 35 vars */]) = 0
  !
  +++ exited with 0 +++
  %
  ```

  the argument passed to `strace`, and thence to `printf`, is exactly the three character long string `!\n`.  `strace` is printing it as a C language string constant, where `\` inside the string is doubled-up, yielding `".\\n"`.  It is `printf` that is interpreting `\n` to mean a linefeed, of course.
- In

  ```
  % strace -e execve printf '!\\\n'
  execve("/usr/bin/printf", ["printf", "!\\\\\\n"], [/* 35 vars */]) = 0
  !\
  +++ exited with 0 +++
  %
  ```

  exactly the same is happening, save that there are more `\`s to double up in the C language string and `printf` is recognizing `\\` followed by `\n`.
- In

  ```
  % strace -e execve printf '!\\\\n'
  execve("/usr/bin/printf", ["printf", "!\\\\\\\\n"], [/* 35 vars */]) = 0
  !\\n+++ exited with 0 +++
  %
  ```

  exactly the same is happening, save that there are more `\`s to double up in the C language string and `printf` is recognizing `\\` followed by `\\` followed by `n`.
- In

  ```
  % strace -e execve printf \!"\\\\n"
  execve("/usr/bin/printf", ["printf", "!\\\\n"], [/* 35 vars */]) = 0
  !\n+++ exited with 0 +++
  %
  ```

  the shell is reducing the argument to `!\\n` because of the escaping rules for double-quoted words in shell language that reduce `\\` and the `\!` quoting to prevent recognition of the history expansion character; the C language string is thus `"!\\\\n"`; and `printf` is seeing `\\` followed by `n`.
- In

  ```
  % strace -e execve printf \!$'\007'"\\\\n"
  execve("/usr/bin/printf", ["printf", "!\7\\\\n"], [/* 35 vars */]) = 0
  !\n+++ exited with 0 +++
  %
  ```

  much the same is happening, except that the C language string escaped form of the `␇` character looks nothing like the shell's, which is using a third form of quoting.

Comment: Quick question, what's your `strace` and `bash` version ? My output for `strace -e execve printf "\!\\\\n"`  (4th example) doesn't match up with yours: I get `execve("/usr/bin/printf", ["printf", "\\!\\\\n"], [/* 42 vars */]) = 0` , i.e. where you have `["printf", "!\\\\n"]` I have `["printf", "\\!\\\\n"]`

Comment: I was trying several ideas for examples, including different shells, and I copied the wrong one.  Here's the right one.

Comment: What are those "ln"?

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro  It's supposed to mean "In the command blah...". Technically unnecessary, but makes for a complete sentence.

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy Thanks. I thought it was a typo.

Comment: About "strace...is trying to write out something that looks roughly like C source code" part. So `strace` is basically trying to give "representation" to what is "literal", right ? Does it mean that C `printf("\n");` treats `\n` as "literal". Can you look at last couple comments under ilkkachu's answer, particularly [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/419146/why-does-number-of-backslashes-increase-in-strace-as-opposed-to-being-reduced-by/419174#comment753145_419174) and tell me if I am getting it right ?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by others, `strace` prints the system call arguments quoted in the same way special characters are quoted in C. A newline is represented as `\n`, a literal backslash as `\\`, a etc.  ([man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html))

> Character pointers are dereferenced and printed as C strings.  Non-printing characters in strings are normally represented by ordinary C escape codes.

It's probably easier to use `set -x` to see what the shell sends to the running command. Bash puts the xtrace output in single-quotes, and backslashes don't take effect within them.

In your first example:

```
$ set -x
$ printf "\\\n" > /dev/null
+ printf '\\n'
```

The first backslash escapes the second, producing a single `\`. The third backslash doesn't escape anything, since it's followed by a letter that doesn't need escaping, so it's taken literally. And the letter is also taken literally, so we get `\\n`. C-quoted, the backslashes are doubled.

The characters that are escaped by a backslash inside double quotes [is explicitly listed in the standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18), they're the dollar sign `$`, backtick `` ` ``, double-quote `"`, backslash itself, `\`, and newline.

The exclamation point is special due to history expansion, but if it's escaped, [the backslash preceding it is *not* removed in Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Double-Quotes.html#Double-Quotes). Zsh however does remove it if history expansion is enabled.

Comment: Do you have any reference to read about C-quoted strings ? I mean, I know about `$'\n'` type of stuff, I've been coding in both C and shell for a while, and I've done the `set -x` part, too, I just didn't include that into my question, but I still don't get what's the purpose of `strace` representing \ as \\ ; it would make sense to escape \ when I type it in at shell prompt, but I don't get why `strace` needs to print it as such, at least to me it appears as there is no need unless `strace` output is expected to be read again by the shell in some way.

Comment: I know this sounds stupid, but ... I don't get it

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy, I think `strace` just uses C-style backslashing to make the listing unambiguous. Especially with newlines, you'll have lots and lots of them in system call arguments anyway. And when you have newline as `\n`, you'll need some way to represent an actual backslash. C-style escapes are common, so why not that. The output of `strace` isn't valid as input for the shell, though, since it uses double-quotes. (and not `$'...'`)

Comment: OK, so to quote [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29024160/3701431) "backlash escape sequences are recognized and expanded to their literal equivalent ", so `strace` effectively does the opposite - it takes the literal and prints it as escape sequence. Is that right ?

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy, mm, yeah, sort of. I think they've mostly tried to give the output as strings you'd use in a C language program, not as something you'd give to the shell. But the backslash-escapes are the same in C and in `$'...'`.

Comment: This is the part that doesn't quite make sense, though. In C language program, I'd do `printf("\n");` and that'd output newline to stdout. By contrast the output of `strace -e execve printf "\n"` gives `["printf", "\\n"]`, and using `printf("\\n");` in C and that'd give `\\n` to stdout; so when you say "strings you'd use in C language program", that's the part that doesn't add up. With  `strace -e execve printf $'\\\n'` there's `["printf", "\\\n"]`, no difference, but outputs `\` and literal newline.

Comment: Is `printf("\n");` in C then understands `\n` as a literal and not as representation, whereas `strace` is supposed to give the opposite ?

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy, in C, `"\\n"` is a string that contains a backslash, and the letter `n`. In the shell `"\n"` is a string that contains a backslash and the letter `n`. In the shell, `'\n'` and `$'\\n'` are two other ways to represent that same thing. Though if we're using the `printf` command as an example, remember that it, also, processes the backslashes, so running `printf "\n"` passes a backslash and `n` to  `printf`, but `printf` outputs a newline.

Answer (score 1):

The number of backslash is indeed reduced by the shell (in one instance).  but expressed as a double backslash in execve "C-quoting".

#### In double quotes (man dash):

> Double Quotes
>        Enclosing characters within double quotes preserves the literal meaning of all characters except dollarsign ($), backquote (`), and backslash (\).  The backslash inside double quotes is historically weird, and serves to quote only the following characters:
>              $ ` " \ <newline>.
>        Otherwise it remains literal.

So, in the line:

```
$ strace -e execve printf "\\\n"
```

the shell changes the arguments a little bit, and this is what strace receive:

```
$ strace -e execve printf "\ \n"     # Space added for emphasis, not real.
```

Only the first backslash will quote the next backslash. Then, the quoting mechanism of execve, where the string is expressed as a "C-quoted" string will double up the number of backslash used, two become four:

```
$ execve("/usr/bin/printf", ["printf", "\\\\n"], [/* 42 vars */]) = 0
```

That is what is seen.

#### In single quotes (man dash):

> Single Quotes
>        Enclosing characters in single quotes preserves the literal meaning of all the characters (except single quotes, making it impossible to put single-quotes in a single-quoted string).

So, strace receives something like this string:

```
strace -e execve printf '\ \ \ \ n'    #space(s) added for emphasis.
```

The four (4) backslash become eight (8) when "C-quoted" by execve:

```
execve("/usr/bin/printf", ["printf", "\\\\\\\\n"], [/* 42 vars */]) = 0
```

This match what is seen in your examples.